# Eclipse Market Place Not Opening

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

Eclipse version that i have installed is:
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2022-12/r

I want to access to the eclipse market place and I am getting the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N09yr.png)

I have tried different solutions from the internet.
a. Have tried to change the network connections to Manual and selected the following options:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rub1a.png)
as suggested by other users.

b. I have tried to add this in environment variables:
_JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

c. I have tried to add the following in the eclipse.ini file:
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

but still my error is not getting resolved.
Please help me with the solution to this problem.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy that intercepts https calls and injects its own certificate?

Comment: No i dont think so.

Comment: Please upgrade, since Eclipse 2022-12 is three releases behind. Your problem might caused by a too old Java with which you run your outdated Eclipse. Better use the current version of Eclipse which is currently 2023-09 with included Java.

Comment: I installed the 2023 - 09 version and initially it was working good for me. But it started giving me the same error. I have installed the necessary software from the marketplace but now i get the same error if i open the marketplace again. So i am facing the same problem again. @howlger

Comment: Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error (do not open it, just select it), hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_.